# Composite Primary key in JPA

Tags: jpa, persistence, eclipselink, composite-primary-key

The EmbeddedId or IdClass annotation is used to denote a composite primary key.
How can i use **composite primary key without ( EmbeddedId or IdClass )** ?

If it is possible to use composite primary key without ( EmbeddedId or IdClass ) then how can i use **EntityManager.find( Entity Class , Object primaryKey) method to find entity in case of composite primary key**(Multiple Primarykey) (because of no IdClass or EmbeddedId) .

EclipseLink take List of pk in the find() operation but if composite pk key defined in example -

```
    Entity Person {
           @Id 
           String username;
           @Id
           String emailId;
           @Basic
           String firstName;
           @Basic
           String lastName;
    }

    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(${username});  //Run time value
    list.add(${emailId});   //Run time value
```

then **EnitityManager.find(list)** will take these arguments , is i am right?

If i am assuming correct then how will EnitityManager.find() operation will know that List 1st argument is username or emailId pk value (means sequence of composite pk fields value)

Comment: In pure JPA, you can't.  It needs a pk class for the find API.  Eclipselink though doesn't need a pk class and can take a collection of values as the pk if you are going away from JPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use a List with the find() operation in EclipseLink.

Answer (score 7):

Let me give my thoughts about it.

```
 find

<T> T find(java.lang.Class<T> entityClass,
           java.lang.Object primaryKey)
```

In order to find an entity of class Person, you should use something like

```
find(Person.class, Object primaryKey)
```

As you have a composed key, you should have a IdClass or EmbeddedId like this.

```
public class PersonKey implements Serializable{

           String username;
           String emailId;

          public PersonKey(String username, String emailId){
                 //Add lines for correct constructor
           }
         //Override hascode and equals
}
```

Then you can find objects based on that key.
find(Person.class, personKey);

your key need to be something like this.

```
PersonKey personKey = new PersonKey(1,1);
Person p = find(Person.class, personKey);
```

**FIND DON'T ACCEPT LISTS IN PURE JPA !!**, accept and return only ONE managed object. If you would use *find* to retrieve several objects you should call the method N times passed the keys you want to find.

If you use find passing a list you will see something like this.

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   Provided id of the wrong type for class domain.model.Person. Expected:
>   class domain.key.PersonKey, got class java.util.ArrayList; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided id of the
>   wrong type for class
>   com.staples.sa.pricemart.domain.model.ItemFileEntity. Expected: class
>   com.staples.sa.pricemart.domain.key.ItemFileKey, got class
>   java.util.ArrayList

It seems eclipseLink have *find* that you can do that, but in order to make you application more portable try to use find as is described in JPA.

Comment: Is there a way to pass only one of the ID element ?
Basically, I want to query all the people who has the same username.

Comment: You could use createQuery or createNativeQuery, the find method won't work as you want as you need to pass the complete composed key.

Answer (score 2):

You should give an entity as the primary key:

```
Person id = new Person();
id.setUsername("Username");
id.setEmailId("EmailId");
entityManager.find(Person.class, id);
```

JPA will use the the fields annotated with `@Id` to find the the record You need.